# how to solve the warning "Clickable images, Lightning button icons, and form elements require labels for mobile users." in LWC html file?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-buttonicon, warning

When I write the code below in the LWC html file, the waring `Clickable images, Lightning button icons, and form elements require labels for mobile users.` is shown.
Anyone knows how to solve it?
My understanding is there is no attribute `label` for [`lightning-button-icon`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon/specification)

```html
<lightning-button-icon
  alternative-text="refresh"
  title="refresh data"
  icon-name="utility:refresh"
  disabled={isDisabled}
  onclick={onClickRefreshButton}
></lightning-button-icon>
```

[image]

Even when I add `label`, `labels` attributes, same warning is show.

[image]

Comment: label is not a documented attribute, however, have you tried adding it? what is the behavior afterwards?

Comment: @glls Thank you for checking my post. Even when I add `label`, `labels` attributes, same warning is show as I edited the post.

Comment: maybe its just a vs code warning, is it affecting your actual deployment?

Comment: @glls Currently, it seems not to affect to the deployment. However, why is it shown and how could I stop this warning?

Comment: I have the same issue. This seems like a bug with the LWC plugin for vscode. The documented properties `title` and `alternative-text` also do not resolve this.

Answer (score 20):

I solved it.
When I put a new **element** `label` inside `lightning-button-icon`, the warning message is not shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to ignore these issues is by adding "<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->" on top of your HTML file. Note that this will only apply to the current file and not affect other HTML files.
You may want to reset VSCode to see the change.

Comment: Restricting that from the settings is better, since no files should be modified, if you have them a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code Preferences, go to **Settings | Extensions | SLDS Validator | Salesforce-vscode-slds | Basic: Mobile Validation.**

Reference: [Use Mobile Validation with Salesforce Lightning Design System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_extensions_slds_validation)